# WCF test client does not recognize my binding

Tags: wcf

I'm guessing (hoping) it's just me not understanding some basic WCF setting.

I have a new web service.  When I add it to WCF Test Client, it pulls up a project with default basic HTTP bindings and I can call the service.

However, when I attempt to add endpoints/bindings for even a very simple service element WCF Test Client never recognizes the bindings and still only presents the one it self-generates.  I've tried many variations but a simple example is:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IReceiveNoteService" sendTimeout="00:05:00" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="ReceiveNoteService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IReceiveNoteService" />
    <endpoint address=""
        name="Testing_IReceiveNoteService"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="MyOwnHttpBinding_IReceiveNoteService"
        contract="IReceiveNoteService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

But the only binding that shows in WCF Test Client is one that it derives itself:

```
IReceiveNoteService (BasicHttpBinding_IReceiveNoteService)
```

**Edit**

I believe I should be seeing an entry for each endpoint with its associated binding:

```
IReceiveNoteService (BasicHttpBinding_IReceiveNoteService)
IReceiveNoteService (MyOwnHttpBinding_IReceiveNoteService)
```

What am I missing to get the test client recognizing my attempts at bindings?

Answer (score 0):

If i am understand correctly you need to change bindingConfiguration property to your binding.

```
bindingConfiguration="yourbindingname"
```

Comment: Thanks.  Isn't that what this [bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IReceiveNoteService"]
in my second endpoint is doing, matching up to this [name="BasicHttpBinding_IReceiveNoteService] in the binding?

Comment: Is BasicHttpBinding_IReceiveNoteService is default binding or is it defined by you?

Comment: I think I'm defining it with:
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IReceiveNoteService" sendTimeout="00:05:00" />
  </basicHttpBinding>

Comment: Can you post expected behavior for this scenario?

Comment: Added.  Also, my apologies.  The example I was using had the same binding name as the default WCF Test Client was generating.  Changed.